# Rounding to whole numbers unevenly spaced apart

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function to assist with my strength training. The program generates a specific weight amount based on a percentage that I need to lift. Instead of giving me 227.44 I want it to round to the nearest value that I have the exact weight of to put on my bar which would be 225. I have written a function that works, but I know there has to be a faster/better way. I'm a CS student, and I'm also going to be modifying this code as I get smaller plates to do my workouts with. How could I implement this in a better way:

```
int getPercentage(double percent, double max){
    int finalValue = max*percent;
    if(finalValue < 45) return 45;
    else if(finalValue >= 45 && finalValue < 55) return 45;
    else if(finalValue >= 55 && finalValue < 65) return 65;
    else if(finalValue >= 65 && finalValue < 80) return 65;
    else if(finalValue >= 80 && finalValue < 95) return 95;
    else if(finalValue >= 95 && finalValue < 105) return 95;
    else if(finalValue >= 105 && finalValue < 115) return 115;
    else if(finalValue >= 115 && finalValue < 125) return 115;
    else if(finalValue >= 125 && finalValue < 135) return 135;
    else if(finalValue >= 135 && finalValue < 145) return 135;
    else if(finalValue >= 145 && finalValue < 155) return 155;
    else if(finalValue >= 155 && finalValue < 170) return 155;
    else if(finalValue >= 170 && finalValue < 185) return 185;
    else if(finalValue >= 185 && finalValue < 195) return 185;
    else if(finalValue >= 195 && finalValue < 205) return 205;
    else if(finalValue >= 205 && finalValue < 215) return 205;
    else if(finalValue >= 215 && finalValue < 225) return 225;
    else if(finalValue >= 225 && finalValue < 235) return 225;
    else if(finalValue >= 235 && finalValue < 245) return 245;
    else if(finalValue >= 245 && finalValue < 260) return 245;
    else return 275;
}
```

Comment: Learn about table/data-driven code.

Comment: You could reduce number of `if` statements by half. There is no difference between two ifs: `finalValue >= 215 && finalValue < 225` + `finalValue >= 225 && finalValue < 235` and one if: `finalValue >= 215 && finalValue < 235`. This would leave you with pretty manageable function. It probably could be done better (without all those if-cases), but if you have very specific range of return values, it may be not worth the hasle.

Answer (score 3):

Well...

```
int getPercentage(double percent, double max){
    int finalValue = max*percent;

    if(finalValue > 260) return 275;
    else if(finalValue >= 235) return 245;
    else if(finalValue >= 215) return 225;
    else if(finalValue >= 170) return 185;
    else if(finalValue >= 145) return 155;
    else if(finalValue >= 125) return 135;
    else if(finalValue >= 105) return 115;
    else if(finalValue >= 80) return 95;
    else if(finalValue >= 55) return 65;
    else return 45

}
```

would definitely be a start.

**Explanation:**

There are a couple of simplifications I have done.

1) A single range to test.
When you have 2 ranges of numbers to test for right next to each other, and landing in the either range will result the same, you can combine them into one. The only real reason to have 2 ranges is if you are doing 2 different things with them, which you're not in the given sample.

2) Highest to lowest.

The second thing I did was re-order your tests to run from highest to lowest. This makes use of the else-if functionality and eliminates the need to test for a ceiling. Remember: Else if  takes the first true condition and executes its block and throws out the rest. Thus, if execution reaches the next else-if, it's safe to assume that the number is not past our ceiling, since our ceiling is immediately next to the previous floor. So, we can just test for the floor making the code more readable.

**Note:** We could have just as easily wrote a similar function lowest to highest as well, but I chose this way because it was easier for me.

And, last but not least,

3) Removed test for both below 45 and 55

This also falls under number 1, as 0-45 and 46-55 are 2 ranges next to each other as well, but I have mentioned them separately for another reason: Their inclusion is unnecessary. As discussed in #2, if else is ever reached, it is safe to assume that the number is less than our ceiling: 55. Again, we only have to check for the floor. Since we have no floor this time (though we could add one later) we don't have anything to check for. Thus, we don't need an else-if, only an else.